# python give a list as input to a function from command line

Tags: python

I am very new to python and basically trying to send a list argument and print it using python

```
 import unittest
 import sys

 class TestStringMethods():
     def test_upper(self, input_list):

         print input_list

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         input_list = sys.argv[1]
         test_upper(input_list)
```

How should i give the input from the command line? I tried this

```
 python test.py 1,2,3
 python test.py test_upper: input_list=[1,2,3]
  python test.py TestStringMethods.test_upper: input_list=[1,2,3]
```

nothing worked

Comment: Why not `input_list = sys.argv[1:]`, then `python test.py 1 2 3`?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

jonrsharpe has already specified this method in comments.

This would be the easiest way to achieve what you want.

You can a give the input numbers separated by spaces as command line arguments.
This can avoid the use of `split` function

Code

```
import sys
input_list = sys.argv[1:]
print (input_list)
```

Output

```
python3 script.py 1 2 3 4 5
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Modifying your code

```
import unittest
import sys
class TestStringMethods:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test_upper(self, input_list):

        print (input_list)


input_list = sys.argv[1:]
c=TestStringMethods()
c.test_upper(input_list)
```

Output

```
python3 script.py 1 2 3 4 5
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work!!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string_input = sys.argv[1]
    input_list = string_input.split(",") #splits the input string on spaces and comma
    # process string elements in the list and make them integers
    input_list = [int(a) for a in input_list]         
    test_upper(input_list)
```

Just to test if the idea works.

Run the following code in idle or any IDE that you are using. I assume you are using python 2.7

```
string_input = "1, 2, 3" 
input_list = string_input.split(",") #splits the input string on spaces and comma 
# process string elements in the list and make them integers 
input_list = [int(a) for a in input_list] 
print input_list
```

Comment: i tried and got this   "python test.py 1,2,3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class TestStringMethods():
  File "test.py", line 18, in TestStringMethods
    test_upper(input_list)
  TypeError: test_upper() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: I have no idea what you do with the test_upper function. You gave it as a function, so I assumed you wrote it correctly. 

The actually solution to this problem is beyond the scope of this question.